# Discord,js bot making a channel

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make my discord bot create a channel! I have tried many way's but none of them work! Note: this is discord.js! Here is the code I have come up with! IT DOES NOT WORK!

```
  guild.channels.create('new-general', { reason: 'Needed a cool new channel' })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'guild' must be defined in some way. You can get it from a message for example by using `message.guild` or even by its name using `client.guilds.find(guild => guild.name === "Guild Name");`

Comment: idk it says guild does not exists

Comment: Could you please edit your question to contain all of your code and not only this line?